# finding the singular points of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the singular points of the following ODE
$(x^2-2x+10)y''+xy'-4y=0$
so rewrite it
$y''+\frac{x}{x^2-2x+10}y'-\frac{4}{x^2-2x+10}y=0$ 
The denominator can't be factored so I guess that means there's no singular points?

Comment: What do you understand under "singular points of ODE"? The points where the coefficient at the highest order derivative vanishes? If yes, then indeed, there're no such points because $x^2-2x+10\ge 9>0$ on $\Bbb R$. Note that this polynomial can be factored over $\Bbb C$.